# Does "precision" of audio files have importance during training ASR systems?

Tags: ffmpeg, kaldi

I am resampling audio files with 8 kHz into 16 kHz by torchaudio.

An example of an original file:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 8000 Hz, 1 channels, s16, 128 kb/s
```

After resampling it's become:

```
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 16000 Hz, 1 channels, flt, 512 kb/s
```

So the precision has been changed to **pcm_f32le**.

I'd like to know if this is important for training of ASR systems or not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, [Kaldi's doc](http://kaldi-asr.org/doc/classkaldi_1_1WaveInfo.html#add7ef2c6c972db48d8f7370164dbe286) says "Support only KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM for now." This makes `pcm_f32le` (which is of `KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_IEEE_FLOAT` type) incompatible. So, save only in a PCM format:

```
torchaudio.save(path, waveform, sample_rate, encoding="PCM_S", bits_per_sample=16)
```

And if you want to increase audio precision, do so only by increasing `bits_pers_sample` (in `PCM_S` encoding).

As for your actual question, it most likely depends on your dataset. So perhaps try both ways and pick the better performing one?